# jQuery library conflict with inline script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript in my wordpress website which also need a jquery library to work correctly. But there is already a library is included in the site that is not working for this code. If i have added the library in the footer with the javascript, then the code will work fine, but that will make some conflict with the other library. Is there any way to use two libraries within a single page without any conflict?

Comment: Do you refer to Jquery as a library here or to two different versions of a plugin using JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) option to use several versions of jQuery at once but you will then still have to see if the plugin you want to use works when it is invoked with a different jQuery version.

Assuming you load two versions via noConflict like so:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var $v3 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You will then be able to use the "1.9" with the global-scoped jQuery variable `$` and the newer version with `$v3`. This could look like the following:

```
var $body = $('body'); // default option

$v3("input-date").datepicker(); // use jQuery v3 to initialize the plugin
```